# Get html element in which a mouse click occurred?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

In javascript I'd like to be able to determine the element in the html page in which a mouse click occurs. Note that the elements will not have an event listener attached.

Basically: cursor somewhere in page, user clicks mouse, capture mouse click event, get element in which click occurred. Is this possible?

One approach I thought of is to get the x,y coords of the click event, iterate through the DOM getting the positions for each element, and finding the inner-most element which contains the click event. Sounds a bit long-winded though - so was wondering if there was another way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org is a very nice website that explains a lot about events.

Especially for your question: [*Event properties - Which HTML element is the target of the event?*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target).

In Internet Explorer, you can get the element from the `event` object with [`event.srcElement`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in all other browsers with [`event.target`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target).

Also see the "Safari bug" workaround in the example I linked to (although I don't know whether it still exist and/or in what version of Safari).

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer, nicely referenced.

Comment: Unfortunately the links are now broken in this post.

Comment: @Alistair: It's a temporary issue: https://twitter.com/ppk/status/648419502728835072

Answer (score 7):

Try [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). There is an example on that page which shows how to use it.

Comment: Maybe it is better to link to [MDC's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) as this is not related to jQuery and could lead to a false conclusion.

Comment: I've linked to the jQuery example because event.target doesn't work in IE, you need event.srcElement there.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.tagName)
}
```

Use document.onclick and e.target give the HTML element.

Source: https://thewebdev.info/2022/02/04/how-to-get-an-html-element-in-which-a-mouse-click-occurred-with-javascript/