# Returning Id of cell when clicked Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm working on creating a table of cells that will change color when each cell is clicked on.

I've created the table and have unique Ids for 'td' element - how do I return the Id of the cell that was clicked so that I can change its background color?

Is it possible to do this with pure JS?

```
const grid = function makeGrid() {
    var body = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td')
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.setAttribute('id', 'makeId' + i + j);
        }
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl)
} 
grid();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know element clicked within a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734736/how-to-know-element-clicked-within-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the click event to the created `cell`

**EDITED:** using Event delegation

```
tblBody.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'TD') {
       console.log(e.target.id)
       e.target.classList.add('bg');
    }
});
```

```js
const grid = function makeGrid() {

  var body = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');

  var tbl = document.createElement('table')
  var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody')

  tblBody.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'TD') {
         console.log(e.target.id)
         e.target.classList.add('bg');
      }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('tr')

    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td')
      cell.innerHTML = 'makeId' + i + j;
      row.appendChild(cell)
      cell.setAttribute('id', 'makeId' + i + j);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl)
}
grid();
```

```css
.bg {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="pixelCanvas">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than set event listeners on every single `td` element, use event delegation.

Set a listener on the table body. It will hear the clicks on the `td` elements. Use the event object's `target` property to determine which `td` was clicked. That is the one the change:

```
document.querySelector('tbody').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

Comment: This will bind the `click` event to every element within the `tbody` element.

Comment: No, it won't. Please expain what you see.

Comment: Yes, it will bind **only** to the `tbody` element. What do you think document.querySelector() returns?

Comment: Your answer is perfect, however the code needs to show how to discard elements different than `TD`.

Comment: Good idea to suggest event delegation, but also you need to check the *event.target* an if not a TD, go up the *parentNode* tree until you find one (now implemented as [*Element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)). That's the TD the OP wants. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I don't disagree, if there were childElements within the TDs (as presented above), you are correct. But given the OP's code, the only possible elements to click upon is a TD or the TextNode inside the TD, which does not have to be isolated.

Comment: Awesome, Glad to help. Also glad you accepted Ele's answer - that'll make him feel better :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn—there was a time when some browsers returned text nodes as the event target if that's what was clicked on. Actually seemed like a good idea to me, but things have moved on…

Comment: You're dating yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Randy, rather than put a listener on every TD you can use event delegation and put the listener on a suitable ancestor, either a parent table section (tbody, thead, tfoot) or the table itself. Then use the event object passed to the listener to get the target of the event. If it's not a TD, go up the parent nodes until you reach a TD.

There is now [*Element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) implemented in most browsers in use, but not IE. So you might want to use a polyfill or simple "upTo" function for those users.

Also, you can take advantage of the *insertRow* and *insertCell* methods of table and table section elements rather than the more long winded *createElement*. Lastly, you can combine creating the element and appending it in one go.

Anyhow, like this:

```js
 
// Create a table with rows rows and cells columns
function genTable(rows, cells) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  // Create tbody and append in one go
  var tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
  tbody.addEventListener('click',highlightCell);
  var row, cell;

  // Use insert methods for less code
  for (var i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    row = tbody.insertRow();

  for (var j=0; j<cells; j++) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.textContent = 'row ' + i + ' cell ' + j;
    }
  }
  // Add entire table to document in one go, easier on host
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

// Highlight cell that was clicked on
function highlightCell(e){
  // Remove highlight from all cells that have it
  document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach(
    node => node.classList.remove('highlight')
  );
  // Add highlight to cell of td in which event occurred
  var cell = e.target.closest('td');
  cell.classList.add('highlight');
}

window.onload = function(){genTable(3, 3);};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Good job, above and beyond. :-)