# How to get ID of an element at a particular coordinate by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Consider there is a DIV on a blank browser page  at coordinate (2,2) in pixels and a button.If i click on the button it must send the coordinates (2,2)  to function which will DETECT what is at (2,2) whether it is a DIV , a BUTTON , etc and also return its ID.

Here is what i tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>elementFromPoint example</title>
    <script>
        function changeColor(newColor) {
            //To get  element from coordinate 2,2
            var elem = document.elementFromPoint(2, 2);
            //Here i wanted to print what i am getting  in var elem
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = elem;
            //next line changes color whatever is at 2,2
            elem.style.color = newColor;
            //But i want to know whats at 2,2 or get its ID or class.
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="para1">Some text here</p> <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button> <span id="status"></span> </body>

</html>
```

But by this method i am only able to change its color, but i am stuck on how can i get its ID or TYPE (div/ button / para / etc).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`event.target`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5181830/2341603).

Comment: ??? You can read all the the properties you need from `elem` in your code.

Comment: The elem is printed as  [object HTMLHtmlElement]

Comment: Thank you very much  to all of you problemis solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var  elem = document.elementFromPoint(2, 2);` gives you the element reference and `id` is a property of that element

Try

```
console.log(elem.id);
```

for type

```
console.log(elem.tagName);
```

To update your status something like:

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'ID:' +elem.id +' , Tag:' +elem.tagName;
```

Comment: I read the question too quickly - you are correct. I deleted my non-answer :)