# Get element under mouse on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension and my goal is the following:

Once a user Ctrl clicks on a username on Reddit, I would like to capture that username on my content script page and send it over to my background page.

Here is how the html in reddit looks like for a random user, the class name is not consistent, so i can not use that.

```
<a class="s1vhwcq3-4 eTpNeg s1461iz-1 gWXVVu" href="/user/strasse86">u/strasse86</a>
```

So far I have being experimenting with the onmouseover just trying to capture the username but without success, since it always returns the first captured result.

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {

    var href = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.className[i].href);

    if ( typeof href != "undefined") {
        if (href.includes("https://www.reddit.com/user/")){
                     // do more actions..
        }
    }   
 };
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: sorry a correction , i am using e.target.className[1].href

Comment: where is 'i' in className[i] coming from?

Comment: Instead of querying by class name, maybe add an id to the anchor element, '<a .. id="reddit"></a>', and query by that? You should have that available to you in e.target.id

Comment: Also, document.getElementsByClassName returns an array based on a class name. The e.target.className[1].href is likely to return you a hyperlink reference, not a class name.

Comment: Yeah it returns the href I want, but it is done only for the first user I have moused over, after that always the same user is returne once I am mouseovering over different users

Comment: You mean add an #id only to the classes that contain usernames or reddit  and then query by that ? how could i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help but this is at least something you can look at.

```js
    window.onmouseover=function(e) {

        var href = e.target.href;

        if ( href) {
            if (href.includes("https://www.reddit.com/user/")){
      console.log('Contains reddit');
            } else {
      console.log('Does not contain reddit');
         }
        }   
     };
```

```html
    <a class="s1vhwcq3-4 eTpNeg s1461iz-1 gWXVVu" href="/user/strasse86">u/strasse86</a>
  <a class="s1vhwcq3-4 eTpNeg s1461iz-1 gWXVVu" href="/user/strasse87">u/strasse87</a>
  <a class="s1vhwcq3-4 eTpNeg s1461iz-1 gWXVVu" href="https://www.reddit.com/user/strasse88">u/strasse88</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onclick = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.tagName)
}
```

Use document.onclick and e.target give the HTML element.

Related Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75472142/12298205